# Problems with Excel Add-In manifest

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to modify an Excel 365 manifest file (to add a ribbon command as now required for MS AppSource)
The file is accepted by the validator (validate-office-addin), but fails when sideloaded in Excel 365

```
Your add-in manifest is not valid.
```

(The previous manifest work here)

Sideloading in local Excel 16 (German) not possible, because there is no option to upload an Addin manifest (there is just "My Add-Ins") which open a web page.

Opening in "File > Options > Add-Ins > XML package" fails for the current and the old Add-In maninfest because ther is a problem with a security certificate.

Is there a way to get a more detailed error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for the problem was that a referenced resid was not defined. (I expected the validation tool to check for that kind or error).

Comment: I have been looking for this for so long. Thank you! It helped me resolve my issue.

Comment: that was my issue as well, thanks for posting the solution

Comment: run this command in cmd

npx office-addin-manifest validate "YOUR MANIFEST FILE"